# #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s) IN

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct, mysql-error-1241

i have a problem with mysql 5.6 version.
Sorry if my english sucks, and sorry if the format is not the right one, im in a hurry.

Mysql throws me this error "#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)" from this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (P.`P_nombre`, P.`P_raza`)

FROM    `Perros` AS P,
        `Adiestramientos` as A

WHERE   P.`P_codigo` = A.`P_codigo` AND A.`A_nroLegajo` = '1500'
AND P.`P_codigo` NOT IN(
        SELECT  A.`P_codigo`
        FROM    `Adiestramientos` as A
        WHERE A.`A_nroLegajo`= '4600'
        )
```

It seems to work fine on Mysql 5.0, the problem seems to be on the IN operator

Hope you can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `A` identifier for the same table twice - in both inner and outer query. Change one into different, e.g. `A2`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.`P_nombre`, P.`P_raza`
FROM    `Perros` AS P,
        `Adiestramientos` as A
WHERE   P.`P_codigo` = A.`P_codigo` AND A.`A_nroLegajo` = '1500'
AND P.`P_codigo` NOT IN(
        SELECT  A2.`P_codigo`
        FROM    `Adiestramientos` as A2
        WHERE A2.`A_nroLegajo`= '4600'
        )
```

Comment: Nope, that query throws me the same error.

Comment: What is the error which you are getting??

Comment: @HernandaSilva:- Did you tried to remove the brackets from your DISTINCT clause????

Comment: @RahulTripathi You're right. It may be the problem here. I missed that.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek:- Lets wait and see what OP gets now for us ;)

Comment: Thanks! the error was in the brackets. Solved!

Answer (score 1):

The [error](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-errors.html) which you get means that:-

MySQL does not support statements of the following form:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE s1 IN (SELECT s2 FROM t2 ORDER BY s1 LIMIT 1)
```

In your case you have to change the indentifier A as it is used twice.

Try this:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.`P_nombre`, P.`P_raza`
FROM    `Perros` AS P,
        `Adiestramientos` as A
WHERE   P.`P_codigo` = A.`P_codigo` AND A.`A_nroLegajo` = '1500'
AND P.`P_codigo` NOT IN(
        SELECT  A1.`P_codigo`
        FROM    `Adiestramientos` as A1
        WHERE A1.`A_nroLegajo`= '4600'
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop the parentheses  in your select list:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        P.`P_nombre`, P.`P_raza`
FROM    `Perros` AS P,
        `Adiestramientos` as A
WHERE   P.`P_codigo` = A.`P_codigo`
        AND A.`A_nroLegajo` = '1500'
        AND P.`P_codigo` NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  A2.`P_codigo`
        FROM    `Adiestramientos` as A2
        WHERE   A2.`A_nroLegajo`= '4600'
        )
```

MySQL does not allow selecting tuples as one field, and `DISTINCT` applies to the whole `SELECT` list anyway.